# What is the python regex to match everything?

Tags: python, regex, django

So I have a django site with only 1 app, but I want to maintain the suggested folder structure so I want all incoming requests to the root url conf to go to that 1 app's urls.py

Essentially I have a structure like

```
site/  
    site/
        urls.py
        settings.py
        ...
    app/
        urls.py
        ...
```

And I want site/urls.py to simply look like this

```
url(r'*matching anything here*', include('app.urls')),
```

I just can't figure out how to make a regex expression to match any set of characters of any length. Essentially EVERYTHING.

I tried using

```
r'(?i).'
```

but it still seems to fail

Comment: `Martjin Pieters` answer is correct. But i would suggest you to use app name prefix instead; while including urls, `url(r'^my_app_name/', include('app.urls'))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `include` you need to give the path prefix; it's `^` in this case:

```
url(r'^', include('app.urls')),
```